# change font color/typeface of a specific textview in listview

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, textview

There are similar questions asked but none of them solves my problem.

I have a listview populated with email messages. What I want to do is to show a different text color and font when the email is not read. So the related code is basically like this:

```
int color = isUnread ? R.color.color_email_unread : R.color.color_email_read;
viewHolder.subject.setTextColor(color);
if (isUnread){
    Typeface font = FontFactory.getInstance().getFont(context, "MyFont"); 
    viewHolder.subject.setTypeface(font);
}
```

But the problem here is that it does not change one specific textview. Let's say the first email is unread and the rest are read. It makes every item in the listview in color_email_read font color and no font change either.

Any idea how to manage it the way I want? The reason is related to Android not re-using the view but couldn't figure out the solution.

UPDATE: It is not related to what isUnread returns as it returns the expected value always:

```
01-30 16:47:42.837: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread: false
01-30 16:47:42.837: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread - subject: linktest3 - text color should be: 2131427330
0
01-30 16:47:42.872: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread: false
01-30 16:47:42.872: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread - subject: subjectttttttttt - text color should be: 2131427330

01-30 16:47:42.922: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread: false
01-30 16:47:42.922: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread - subject: unread test - text color should be: 2131427330

01-30 16:47:42.972: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread: true
01-30 16:47:42.972: D/EmailListAdapter(5837): isUnread - subject: from unread test - text color should be: 2131427340
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be related to however isUnread is being populated. If it is always false, then it obviously would make all of your items color_email_read. It really should be pulled from something in your adapter's data source rather than anything associated with the view itself.

Also, this is actually the opposite of your problem, but I believe if you leave the if(isUnread) the way it is in your code, you will have items appearing in the unread font that are actually read. Unless you already have code that does this somewhere else, you should add something like this to avoid that problem:

```
if(isUnread) {
     ...
} else {
     viewHolder.subject.setTypeFace(whatever_your_read_font_is);
}
```

Comment: It is not related to what isUnread returns, please check my update.